# How change name of file "projects" and set it in init.el?

Tags: init-file, project

Emacs 27.2

In `~/.emacs.d/projects`

This file content all my projects.
[image]

press `d`
[image]
But I need to change file name. E.g. `projects-laptop`.

Is it possible and and set it name on `init.el` file?

P.S. For bookmarks has variable: `bookmark-default-file`

But I need same for file `projects`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the variable `project-list-file`. For example, try `(setq project-list-file "~/.emacs.d/projects-laptop")`. The variable docstring says "File in which to save the list of known projects."

I am using Emacs 27.1 and the `project` v0.8 is installed from [GNU Elpa](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/project.html).